# Maven Script for include files in in jars

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-release-plugin

How do i include config folder in jar file.
let say i have one services project
**services/src/config/adp/flt/get.flt**
there is one flt file in config folder.
So i want to include that folder in services.jar using maven script
I have tried different solution copy-resources but it is copying that folder on target folder not in services.jar

Answer (score 5):

Try the [Maven Resource Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html):

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
         <directory> [your folder here] </directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Alternatively, you could move your files to a sub directory of Maven's default resource folder, `src/main/resources`. In that way, they get included automatically.